# Eclipse can't find older android SDKs even though I've downloaded them

Tags: android, eclipse, platform

I have Android 4.2 installed and working in Eclipse. I'd now like to test my app with older SDK versions.

I've used "Android SDK Manager" to download these older SDK versions, and they show up as "Installed" there, and I can create AVDs using those platforms, but when in Eclipse, only my 4.2 AVDs show up.

Also strange: If I browse to:

```
E:\adt\sdk\platforms
```

... the only directory is:

```
android-17
```

So where is 'android-10' that I have downloaded via the SDK manager?

[image: Android SDK Manager]

When I go to preferences in Eclipse, as mentioned, only 4.2 shows up:

[image: Eclipse preferences]

What gives?!

Comment: Check whether you don't have two sdk's in your system. There can be multiple sdk's get installed in the system by mistake And you are updating the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK Path on your SDK Manager window says that the path is E:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk. You are trying to search in E:\adt\sdk\platforms and it is not there.

Comment: So here's my best guess as to what happened: Perhaps I installed the Android SDK on two different occasions. Perhaps there are two ways to install it: (1) Via an installer, (2) By unzipping into a directory. I probably did (2) most recently and launched Eclipse via that route, leading to it using E:\adt\sdk. And when trying to launch the SDK Manager, I probably clicked Start -> Programs -> Android -> SDK Manager, and it used the older install, which was in Program Files. Who knows.

Comment: You probably had 2 installs from the looks of it. Just point the Eclipse preferences at the location for your current SDK Manager Path.

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking my ANDROID_HOME environment variable I was confused to find:

E:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

And upon further inspection, the SDK Manager also shows that in the screenshot above. So obviously something strange has happened.

Trying to figure out how to get things sane again...